# Ошибка в работе с библиотекой gumbo

Tags: c++

Полностью скопировал код с официальной странички с гитхаба - https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser#basic-usage
Единственное что поменял это #include "gumbo.h" на #include "src\gumbo.h"

Но при компиляции появляется ошибка с таким текстом:

[image: Текст ошибки]

Как исправить? Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить из-за чего она появляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы использовать бо́льшую часть библиотек, недостаточно сделать `#include ...`.

Библиотеку нужно скомпилировать отдельно, а потом при компиляции вашей программы указать  получившийся файл (на MinGW нужно подключать файлы вида `libНазваниеБиблиотеки.a`, флажком `-lНазваниеБиблиотеки`).

Уже собранная gumbo похоже есть в MSYS2, так что компилировать самому необязательно.

Ставим MSYS2 [отсюда](http://www.msys2.org/), обновляемся (`pacman -Syu`, перезапуск msys, `pacman -Su`), ставим gumbo (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gumbo-parser`).

Дальше ищем что-нибудь вроде `libgumbo.a` в `путь_до_msys2\mingw64\lib` и пробуем подключить.